# MySQL permissions or privileges (User does not have access to metadata required)

Tags: mysql, permissions

I am using MySQL and I need to give one user to web service for access  database.

The web service need all permission related to stored procedure, like procedure execution.

I executed the following statements:

```
CREATE USER testservice@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test$123';
GRANT EXECUTE ON TestDB.* TO 'testservice'@'%';
```

but when run the web service , web service produces the following error:

```
User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored procedure 
parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure connection with 
"noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters that represent 
INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.
```

So, what do I need to do? Can any one help me?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986628/cant-execute-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-java